# Proguard simple example error

Tags: java, android, proguard

Is my first time using Proguard. I'm testing it in a example project with following code (Just for check when the stacktrace is obfuscated)

```
package com.proguardtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ProguardTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try{
        Integer.parseInt("Test");
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

So I create a new project and go to the file:
**default.properties** and add the line

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

thats the resulting file:# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.

```
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "build.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Project target.
target=android-7
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

Then I try to generate the apk with the export wizard (Eclipse Windows) and at the last step when I have selected the path for the apk a error dialog appears showing Conversion to dalvik failed.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you changed something in the build.xml file before using the above way by any chance?
Try creating a new project with the same Activity and default.properties file. From the way it looks, it should obfuscate your APK with no particular problem...

Comment: I didn't touch any build.xml file (dont even find it ^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to ProGuard 4.6 ([download it](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/4.6/), extract the .zip file, copy to ..\android-sdk\tools\proguard)